# expectation of the trace of the square root of wishart matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $X(N,N)$  be Wishart matrix with rank(X)=K in order to estimate the expectation of the trace of the square root of X i.e $X^{1/2}$ I want to know if is possible to use the unordered Wishart distribution function to estimate this value?

\begin{align}
E[trace(\sqrt X )]=?
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the trace is invariant under unitary transformations, you can work in a basis where $X$ is diagonal, with nonzero elements $x_n$, $n=1,2,\ldots K$ on the diagonal; denote by $P(x)$ their marginal distribution; then 
$$\mathbb{E}[{\rm tr}\, \sqrt X]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^K\sqrt{x_n}\right]=K\int P(x)\sqrt{x}\,dx.$$
For $K\gg 1$ you can use the [Marcenko-Pastur distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko%E2%80%93Pastur_distribution) for $P(x)$.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker sir can I used the distribution of the unordered eigenvalue   \begin{align}    f(\lambda ) = \frac{1}{K}{\sum {\frac{{i!}}{{(i + N - K)!}}{{[L_i^{N - K}(\lambda )]}^2}\lambda } ^{N - K}}{e^{ - \lambda }}\end{align} wher $L$ represent the lagrangien polynom

Comment: yes, the order is irrelevant.

Comment: sir I have tried to estimate the expectation using the distribution of the unordered eigenvalue. however, when I compare this result to the result obtained numerically (using Matlab) I find that there are not similar?

Comment: As a test, you could first try large K and use the Marcenko -Pastur distribution.

Comment: using he Marcenko -Pastur distribution i can't find a finite form of this equation?

Comment: It is just an integral you have to evaluate.